# Debugging deployed azure app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Is it possible to attach to a deployed Azure app? I would like to be able to step through the code so that I can see what values are being set in a request to one of my web role actions.

I have looked around and the only examples seem to be of debugging when the azure app is running on the local machine.

Answer (score 9):

[Windows Azure Tools (June 2010)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2274a0a8-5d37-4eac-b50a-e197dc340f6f&displaylang=en) allows to use IntelliTrace in the cloud. This release:

> Adds **support for debugging services in the cloud by using the Visual Studio 2010 IntelliTrace** feature. This is enabled by using the deployment feature, and logs are retrieved through Server Explorer.

**IntelliTrace support requires**:

- .NET 4
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- the cloud service has to be deployed with IntelliTrace enabled

Comment: +1 for Rinat's answer. Just one clarification: to take advantage of IntelliTrace, your roles must target .NET 4 (another new feature of the June 2010 release).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't debug an Azure app running on MS's servers.

You might be able to solve your problem with Azure's [logging](https://web.archive.org/web/20091213034111/http://microsoftpdc.com:80/Sessions/SVC15?) feature, though.

**Edited to add** MS just announced [IntelliTrace for the cloud fabric in the June 2010 tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jnak/june-2010-release-of-the-windows-azure-tools-sdk).

Answer (score 1):

Craig is right "today" you cannot debug an Azure App running on cloud fbaric, you can only debug on local fabric.
you may want to look at the diagonostic and logging API
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140407025533/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2009/12/01/introducing-windows-azure-diagnostics.aspx)
http://blog.benday.com/archive/2008/11/07/23201.aspx

this is a great tool - http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Adding one more thing to Rinat's answer: I did attend a session on Intellitrace and one of things I was told that it should never be used on your applications running in production slot as it creates quite an overhead. So you may want to deploy your application in staging slot do all the cloud debugging and then remove Intellitrace once you find the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336122.aspx

This will help u..

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to deploy the Visual Studio 2012 remote debugging tools to a Windows Azure Cloud Service and attach to the remote process.  The following BLOG post explains an approach.
http://www.fullscale180.com/Blog/post/2012/10/07/Remote-Debugging-Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services-with-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx

[This sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Debugging-Windows-dedaaec9)
 demonstrates remotely debugging Windows Azure Cloud Services with Visual Studio 2012.  The sample utilizes Visual Studio 2012 remote debugging tools and provides an approach to deploy these tools with a cloud service, allowing us to attach to the deployed instance from the Visual Studio 2012 IDE using the remote debugging features.

Comment: Windows Azure SDK 2.2 release adds support for remote debugging many types of Windows Azure resources.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/10/22/windows-azure-announcing-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-2-with-lots-of-goodies.aspx